# Principal Component Analysis and Rotation

Tags: opencv, image-processing, pca, image-rotation

I have implemented a PCA in order to assign rotation information to connected 2D points extracted from images (edge fragments, see data points in image below for examples). I want the information to be robustly reproducible under rotation of the data so that I can use it for recognition purposes (comparable to [1](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~zwp/teach/MVA/pcaimg.pdf)). For this purpose, I want the principal components (eigenvectors) to rotate with the points (+- 180 deg).

My implementation includes a mean centring of the data. I have also tested the implementations of OpenCV and one in Python which yield to the same results. This is why I assume that my implementation is correct and that the problem is the method itself. I had quite good results  for other 2D distributions. Nonetheless, for these specific data points, it does not seem to work.

I have done all the tests with and without normalization to the standard deviation (ie., dividing the data of the x and y values by their standard deviations).

Here are my results for different rotations of the data (extracted from images):

[PCA Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Zfz.png)

As can be seen, the method does not allow to find a reproducible rotation. The data is affected by quantization (because it is extracted from images) which is why I had the idea that this is the origin of the problem. Therefore I repeated the experiment with added random noise (4th column). As can be seen, this does not seem to be the problem.

I have no precise idea how to explain the displayed effects. I note that the general orientation of the principal axes seems to be similar in the first and second row, respectively. I think that this means something, but what exactly? Can I somehow solve the problem or are there possibly better methods for such a problem? Due to some preprocessing it can be assumed that there are no outliers.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: in your results, 1st and 2nd column always have the same rotation. This looks like a bug, like if you always display the first rotation (even if you calculated both). Also, PCA is not good for modelling such data shapes.

Comment: Every column shows the same data/rotation. Four different rotations are analyzed here. The difference is that the top row shows the results without normalization and the second row the results with normalization. This is no bug but the experimental setup to analyze the effect of the normalization. Note that I received the same results with external implementations of PCA - I think this indicates that there is no bug in the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For symmetrycal shapes like you shown you can try symmetry detector like this: https://github.com/subokita/Sandbox/tree/master/FSD

On examples it give results like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, my data is not always symmetrical. Maybe it is the symmetry which affects the results here that strong. Because for other fragments I tested, which are not that symmetrical, the results of the PCA are quite stable under rotation.